# Quit program when destructor is run in class

Tags: c++, sdl

I am trying to get my program to end when the destructor of the object is called. Its part way working because the object is deleted but the program is still running. Is there any way to do this? Or is this a wrong way to do this with a better way? Thank you for all the help! Its much appreciated!

here is the main function

```
#include "engine.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    bool running = true;
    Engine engine;
    engine.init();

    while(running == true) {
        engine.update();
        engine.render();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the object .cpp

```
#include "engine.h"

Engine::Engine() {
}

void Engine::init() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    screen = SDL_CreateWindow("Engine", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 960, 540, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(screen, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    if(screen == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Could not create window: " << SDL_GetError() <<  std::endl;
    }
}

void Engine::update(){
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);
    if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
        delete this;
    }
}

void Engine::render() {
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

Engine::~Engine() {
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: Don't know anything about SDL, but is it creating some threads that don't get stopped?

Comment: @kmort right im trying to see if there is a way to end the program when the object is destroyed because without the game object you have no game lol

Comment: Are you saying that when the `Engine` destructor is called you want to quit the program? If so, you can just use `exit();` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/

Comment: @kmort that is exactly what I just did before I read your comment. If you would like to put that as an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Good luck. :-)

Comment: `delete this` has undefined behavior when `this` points to an object that wasn't allocated with `new`, as is the case for your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to end your program when the `Engine` destructor is called, you can use `exit();`

Take a quick look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/) for more information.

Comment: Since this seems to be doing window management, calling `exit()` might be a bad idea. There are local destructors that might need to be run and legacy C library cleanup functions to be called.

Answer (score 2):

Using an exception is probably the most graceful way to exit from deeply nested code, since it ensures that the stack is unwound and everything is properly destroyed. I would define an empty type solely to be thrown for this exception, probably nested inside `Engine`:

```
class Engine {
public:
  // ...
  struct ExitException {};
  // ...
};
```

and throw it from `Engine::update` to exit:

```
void Engine::update(){
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);
    if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
        throw ExitException();
    }
}
```

which you can catch in `main` to exit cleanly:

```
int main() {
    Engine engine;
    engine.init();

    try {
        while(true) {
            engine.update();
            engine.render();
        }
    } catch(Engine::ExitException&) {}
}
```